# linux: links don't work after mount

Tags: linux, mount, symbolic-link

This is not your classic programming question and since I'm quite new to this (really cool!) site, I'm not sure if this is the place, so I'll try anyway.

I work in a lab when all the guys use PCs with Windows and access the lab linux servers via ssh.

I prefer linux, so I have a local installation of ubuntu 10.4 on my PC. I mount the home of our lab server using mount server:/home /mnt/home/. I can then access the files on the server (I had to change my local UID to match the one assigned to me on our server in order to be able to write to my home dir).

The problem is all the (symbolic) links I have on the server don't work when I access them through the mounted location. I guess the system simply tries following the link in my local /home instead on server:/home.

Is there a way to make the links work?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Move to serverfault.com?

Comment: The sister site http://superuser.com is a better place for non-programming questions.

Comment: Maybe, but it's also server-related.

Comment: Double-post! Here's the "parent post" By David B: http://superuser.com/questions/167722/linux-make-links-work-after-mount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A symbolic link (unlike a hard link) is simply a "file" that contains the destination file.

So you're right. If the symbolic link contains `/home/bob`, then that's the file it will attempt to use, *not* `server:/home/bob`.

I don't think there's an way around this other than to:

- mount `server:/home` over your `home` directory, not a good idea since it'll hide your real `home` filesystem; or
- mount all softlinks under your own `home` as well, not a good idea just due to mount management issues.

Comment: The reason people keeping asking questions, non related to programming, is because people keep supplying answers here.

Comment: That's fine, @Anders, both the Q&A will soon get migrated to SU/SF. Lack of answers won't stop the barbarian hordes from posting here :-)